# How to split array in two other arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I extract the key and the value of an array into two separate arrays, with autoincrementing integers as keys:

Ex:

```
Base:
Array ( [MX] => 13 ); 

Array 1:
Array ( [0] => MX ); 

Array 2:
Array ( [0] => 13 );
```

This with some neat php function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
$array1 = array_keys($base);

$array2 = array_values($base);
```

Answer (score 4):

use `array_keys()` and

```
array_values()
```

**Array Keys**

```
$array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
print_r(array_keys($array));
```

**Result**

Array

```
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => color
)
```

**Array Values**

```
$array = array("size" => "XL", "color" => "gold");
print_r(array_values($array));
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => XL
    [1] => gold
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1= array_keys($base_array);
$array2= array_values($base_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)